# Batch process in c#

Tags: c#, process, batch-file

I am having a Java batch process which I used in C# to run  process. I want to have a testcase  to check whether the batch process is running or not.

I used the batch process as:

```
void batch_process(string process)
{
    try
    {
        string strFilePath = Path.Combine(batch_process_path, process);
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(strFilePath);
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psi.WorkingDirectory = batch_process_path;
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.ErrorDialog = true;
    }
}
```

How can this test be done?

I want to write an unit test case to check whether the process will start or not.

Comment: This code will not start a process. It simply initializes an instance of ProcessStartInfo.

Comment: He is just asking how to check if it's still running.

Answer (score 2):

when you `Start` your new process you need to capture the returned `Process`, that provides access to newly started process, useful for starting, stopping, controlling, and monitoring applications.

```
 Process exe = Process.Start(psi);
    ....

 if exe.HasExited() ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You could start the process using

```
Process process = new Process();
string strFilePath = Path.Combine(batch_process_path, process);
process.StartInfo.FileName = strFilePath;

//this line will hold this thread until the process is done.
process.WaitForExit();
```

then start the process on a different thread and let that thread fire an event after `process.WaitForExit();` is done.

Answer (score 1):

You should first start the process using the `ProcessStartInfo` you've just created like:

```
Process process = Process.Start(psi);
```

then you can use `process.HasExited` to check if the process has exited. Often, you don't need to do this, as process.WaitForExit() blocks the code until process exits.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit unsure of the scenario from your question... but 4 techniques you can use are:

- if you have started the process using `var process = Process.Start(psi);` then:

  - you can periodically check `process.HasExited` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx
  - or you can subscribe to `Process.Exited` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx
  - or you can block on `Process.WaitForExit` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit.aspx
- if your process is started in some other way and has some unique name, then you can inspect the enumeration returned by `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()` to determine if your batch process is currently running.

In general... I'd prefer to use `Process.Exited`, but the other methods all have their place too!